# ¿Cómo mantener vivo varios servicios en segundo plano luego de cerrar la aplicación?

Tags: android, procesos-en-segundo-plano

Soy relativamente nuevo en android y me encuentro con el siguiente escenario:

- La aplicación, luego de iniciar sesión, nunca debería caer y en caso de que lo haga debería poder levantarse sola.
- La aplicación tiene 3 servicios diferentes que son los que deberían funcionar siempre en segundo plano (dos interactúan entre ellos y el otro es completamente independiente).

El problema es que actualmente no logro mantener la aplicación activa (en segundo plano) 24/7 y dependiendo del dispositivo en el que pruebe, la aplicación se cae enseguida o incluso luego de varias horas y no se vuelve a levantar.

Los permisos que tengo en el mainfest son:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

He intentado lograr esto en una aplicación nueva con un broadcast receiver dentro del mainfest o también declarándolo desde el main, sin olvidar que dentro del servicio sí tengo implementado lo siguiente:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Ahora bien, como empecé diciendo, soy relativamente nuevo en android y posiblemente esté aplicando mal alguna de estas cosas o no sé si de por sí, con esto de la optimización de la batería, ya no es posible mantener vivo un servicio 24/7.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a tu información tu servicio iniciará cuando inicie el sistema operativo de tu dispositivo `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`, y es correcto usar `START_STICKY` para poder recrear el servicio si la aplicación se destruye.

Para las nuevas versiones del sistema operativo android, es necesario usar el permiso `FOREGROUND_SERVICE`:

```
 <uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE”></uses-permission>
```

EL problema radica en que en onStartCommand() no se encuentra el proceso que realizarà tu servicio, agrégalo aquí y no en otro método del servicio

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    
    //Proceso...
    
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola con las nuevas políticas de administración de energía mata todos los servicios después de cierto tiempo, para saltar esta política debes entraren tu Android a configuración/Apps y notificaciones/Avanzado/Acceso especial a apps/Optimización de la batería.
Aquí cambias a todas y buscas tu app seleccionas y marcas la opción optimizar

[image: permisos especiales]
[image: Optimizar bateria]

[image: Selecciona todas]

Comment: Hola David, te respuesta no parece estar relacionada con la pregunta, te sugiero ver  ver [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada,