# ¿Cómo mantener trabajando un servicio aun cuando la APP se cierre?

Tags: android-studio, servicio

Tengo el siguiente código para ejecutar un servicio el cual funciona bien mientras la APP este abierta.

Sin embargo he notado que cuando cierro la APP ya sea oprimiendo botón atrás del celular o oprimiendo el botón **cerrar todo** del celular, el servicio también se cierra y se cancela.

He modificado el código según otras consultas que he visto pero no logro que me funcione.

¿Cómo hago para que el servicio no se cancele y siga trabajando en background aun cuando la APP se haya cerrado?

Código MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent servicio = new Intent(this, servicio.class);
           startService(servicio);  

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

Código Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<service
        android:name=".Servicio"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />

<receiver android:name="ReceiverCall" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.linamar.Servicio" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Código servicio:

```
public class Servicio extends Service {

public servicio() {
}

private Thread workerThread = null;
private Context thisContext=this;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Toast.makeText(this, "INICIANDO SERVICIO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    if(workerThread == null || !workerThread.isAlive()){
        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){

                for (int i = 1; i>=0; i++){

                    try{

                        Thread.sleep( 3600000 );

                        //codigo de notificacion cada 24 horas
               
                    }catch (Exception e){

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
            }
        });
        workerThread.start();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("Servicio.class");
    sendBroadCast(intent); 
}


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

}
```

Código BroadcastReceiver

```
public class ReceiverCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Servicio.class);
    context.startService(intent);

}

}
```

Comment: @Jorgesys buenas tardes, he observado sus respuestas en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48197/mantener-un-servicio-android-siempre-vivo y https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/579306/c%c3%b3mo-mantener-vivo-varios-servicios-en-segundo-plano-luego-de-cerrar-la-aplicac con  similares problemas al mio, y aunque he hecho modificaciones no logro que me funcione, me podría dar una mano por favor.